# Strongly typing ID values in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to strongly type integer ID values in C#?

I've recently been playing with Haskell and can immediately see the advantages of its strong typing when applied to ID values, for example you would never want to use a *PersonId* in place of a *ProductId*.

Is there a nice way to create an *Id* class/struct that can be used to represent IDs of a given type?

I had the following idea but unfortunately it **isn't legal** on many levels. You can't have an abstract struct and the implicit/explicit cast operators wouldn't be inherited.

```
public abstract struct Id
{
    int _value;

   public Id(int value)
   {
      _value = value;
   }

   // define implicit Id to int conversion operator:
   public static implicit operator int(Id id) 
   {
      return _value;    
   }

   // define explicit int to Id conversion operator:
   public static explicit operator Id(int value) 
   {
      return new Id(value);
   }

   public bool Equals(object obj)
   {
      if(GetType() == obj.GetType()) 
      {
         Id other = (Id)obj;
         return other._value == _value;
      }
      return false;
   }

   public int GetHashCode()
   {
      return _value.GetHashCode();
   }
}

struct PersonId : Id { public PersonId(int value) : base(value) {} }
struct ProductId : Id { public ProductId(int value) : base(value) {} }
```

Are there any valid ways to perform something similar?  How else can we prove that integer IDs type aren't being confused across a large application?

Comment: Seems like a solution looking for a problem.  If your design allows this kind of issue to happen, your design is the problem, not the fact that both ids are ints.  YAGNI, IMHO, LOL.

Comment: I disagree, it isn't down to design, there are plenty of times with the best design, that mistyping a field name could easily end up with the wrong int in the wrong id field. Database referential integrity only helps so far, right up to the point that the integer you are testing with is valid for both the right and wrong field...

Comment: @Will =) Hmm Im not entirely sure what the OP is trying to encapsulate.

Comment: @Will large legacy system, I'm afraid the damage is done.  Though I would still argue that this feature could bring a lot of benefits to many systems.

Comment: @Will This is actually common practice when applying DDD

Comment: The problem you are trying to avoid is transposition of arguments of the same time in a method call, which can and does happen more than you would like, especially if you are trying to refactor an existing application. The implicit and explicit conversions will bite you and should definitely be removed

Comment: I've since discovered that the language feature I'm dreaming of is called "nominal types"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
public interface IId { }

public struct Id<T>: IId {
    private readonly int _value;

    public Id(int value) {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public static explicit operator int(Id<T> id) {
        return id._value;
    }

    public static explicit operator Id<T>(int value) {
        return new Id<T>(value);
    }
}

public struct Person { }  // Dummy type for person identifiers: Id<Person>
public struct Product { } // Dummy type for product identifiers: Id<Product>
```

Now you can use types `Id<Person>` and `Id<Product>`. The `Person` and `Product` types can be either structs or classes. You can even use the actual types that are identified by the id and in that case you do not need any dummy types.

```
public sealed class Person {
    private readonly Id<Person> _id;
    private readonly string _lastName;
    private readonly string _firstName;

    // rest of the implementation...
}
```

The explicit operator overloads allow safe and easy casting between id types and underlying id values. When working with legacy interfaces you may want to change the casting to integer to be implicit, or even better, to overload the legacy interfaces with properly typed versions. Extension methods can be used when the legacy interface is from a third party and cannot be changed or overloaded directly.

```
public interface ILegacy {
    public bool Remove(int user);
}

public static class LegacyExtensions {
    public static bool Remove(this ILegacy @this, Id<Person> user) {
        return @this.Remove((int)user);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Added `IId` interface as suggested by smartcaveman.

**Edit:** Changed both operators to be explicit after thinking about Alejandro's suggestion and added a section how to deal with legacy interfaces.

Comment: thanks, I like this idea, I'm toying with it though I might have to create a few dummy classes to represent IDs that don't correspond directly to entities in C#

Comment: +1, I like this solution, but I think two improvements could be made.  (1) Make the class implement an interface `IId`, for circumstances when you need the value, but don't want to be coupled to the class of the object that is being identified, (2) Make it an `Id<T,TId> where TId:struct`, thus allowing you to use the class for other Identity value types like a `long` or `Guid`, which is probably a likely use.

Comment: @chillitom: Yes, if you don't have good candidates for identifier types, it is better to use dummy types. I would use either structs (as in my example) or sealed classes with private default constructor.

Comment: @smartcaveman: The `IId` interface is a good idea. However, I do not agree with your second suggestion. If the number of identifier types is reasonable, I would define a new struct for each of them: `Id<T>, LongId<T>, GuidId<T>`. I would do this because I prefer writing `GuidId<Person>` instead of `Id<Person, Guid>`.

Comment: I like this option, this could avoid some errors originating from typos and mixing with other ints. However I would suggest a small change. I would switch the implicit and explicit operators, so that the implicit converts **to** `Id<T>` and the explicit **from** `Id<T>` to `int`, because I find more "dangerous" to break out of the shell this struct provides than to accidentally get into it, and preventing such mixings is the main purpose of the struct to begin with. If you want the int, ask for it explicitly, otherwise let the compiler blow up.

Comment: @Alejandro, I do see your point and I do agree. I presumed that the types are used with legacy interfaces in which case the implicit casting is a desired feature for convenience. When that is not the case, it does make more sense to have them switched around.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing how to do Id comparisons, I found adding these to be helpful: `
  public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Id<T> other && this.Equals(other);
  public bool Equals(Id<T> other) => this._value == other._value;
  public static bool operator ==(Id<T> lhs, Id<T> rhs) => lhs.Equals(rhs);
  public static bool operator !=(Id<T> lhs, Id<T> rhs) => !lhs.Equals(rhs);`

Answer (score 3):

Well, in my experience, operator overloading in such scenarios usually doesn't work too well and can lead to all kinds of problems. Also, if you provide implicit cast operators to/from type `int`, are you sure that a statement such as:

```
SomeCompany.ID = SomePerson.ID
```

will still get caught as invalid by the compiler? Or might the compiler just use your cast operators and thus let the invalid assignment through...?

A less elegant solution involves defining your own value object type (as a `class`) and accessing the actual ID via a `Value` property:

```
sealed class PersonId
{
    readonly int value;
    public int Value { get { return value; } }

    public PersonId(int value)
    {
        // (you might want to validate 'value' here.)
        this.value = value;
    }

    // override these in order to get value type semantics:
    public override bool Equals(object other) { … }
    public override int GetHashCode() { … }
}
```

Now, whenever you would write `person.Id`, you'll need to write `person.Id.Value` if you actually need the raw integer. It would be even better if you actually tried to reduce access to the raw integer value to as few places as possible, e.g. where you persist an entity to (or load it from) a DB.

**P.S.:** In the above code, I would really like to make `PersonId` a `struct`, since it's a value object. However, `struct`s have one problem, which is a parameter-less constructor that's automatically provided by the compiler. This means that a user of your type can bypass all your constructors (where validation might happen), and you might end up with an invalid object right after construction. Thus, try to make `PersonId` as similar to a `struct` as possible: by declaring it `sealed`, by overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, and by not providing a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 2):

From C#9 forward you can use **records** to define strongly typed IDs.

```cs
public record ModelId(Guid Id);
public record MyModel(ModelId Id, string Data /*...*/);
```

Comparison operators, equality methods and `GetHashCode` are automatically implemented

> To enforce value semantics, the compiler generates several methods for your record type (both for record class types and record struct types):
>
> - An override of Object.Equals(Object).
> - A virtual Equals method whose parameter is the record type.
> - An override of Object.GetHashCode().
> - Methods for operator == and operator !=.
> - Record types implement System.IEquatable.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late for an answer (suggestion actually), but I thought about this problem, and toyed around with an idea, that might be helpful.

Basically the idea is to create an identity factory for each type, returning the interface for the actual id instance.

```
public interface IPersonId
{
    int Value { get; }
}

public static class PersonId
{
    public static IPersonId Create(int id)
    {
        return new Id(id);
    }

    internal struct Id : IPersonId
    {
        public Id(int value)
        {
            this.Value = value;
        }

        public int Value { get; }

        /* Implement equality comparer here */
    }
}
```

It a bit of work, and it won't work with an ORM, unless it has access to the internal `struct`, so unless that is a problem, the idea should be safe.
This is a rough draft, and I haven't tested thoroughly myself, but so far I get value types for id's and there is no issue with the parameterless `struct` constructor.

If you like, the solution could be made generic as well (inspiration from the other posters), like so:

```
public interface IId<T>
{
    int Value { get; }
}

public static class Id
{
    public static IId<T> Create<T>(int value)
    {
        return new IdImpl<T>(value);
    }

    internal struct IdImpl<T> : IId<T>
    {
        public IdImpl(int value)
        {
            this.Value = value;
        }

        public int Value { get; }

        /* Implement equality comparer here */
    } 
}
```

Then you would be able to do `Id.Create<Person>(42)`.

Personally I'm not a huge fan of these kinds of generics, but I guess it's a matter of taste really. It's really just a way of constraining type compatibility, which in my opinion should be explicit.
The advantage, though, is that you would only have a single place to do equality comparison, which is nice and DRY.

It's definitely not perfect and in most (if not the majority) of use cases it would be completely over engineered, just to get around the fact that `struct`s has a default parameterless constructor.
Furthermore there is no way to do validation checks on the generic variation, for obvious reasons, and the underlying id value is constrained to `int` (which could be changed of course).

Comment: I just stumbled upon an article describing the issue I pointed out regarding the first suggestion: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/01/03/value-objects-explained/

Answer (score 1):

You create an abstract base class from which you can derive your strongly-typed identifier objects.

```
public abstract class TypedGuid
{
    protected TypedGuid(Guid value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public Guid Value { get; }
}
```

Then you inherit from that:

```
public class ProductId : TypedGuid
{
    public ProductId (Guid value) : base(value)
    { }
}
```

In the abstract base class, you could also implement the `IEquatable`, `IFormattable` and the `IComparable` interfaces. You could also override the `GetHashCode` and `ToString` methods.

```
public abstract class TypedGuid
{
    protected TypedGuid(Guid value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public bool HasValue => !Value.Equals(Guid.Empty);
    public Guid Value { get; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Value.GetHashCode();
    public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();
}
```

You could also provide static methods on the typed objects to conveniently create instances with empty values.

```
public class ProductId : TypedGuid
{
    public static ProductId Empty => new ProductId(Guid.Empty);
    public static ProductId New => new ProductId(Guid.NewGuid());

    public ProductId(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

You could also add implicit operators to allow implicit conversion, however that may arguably defeat the robustness and purpose of having the identifiers be strongly typed.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why you would want `PersonID` to be a class on its own, PersonID would be a **property of** person of type `int`.

`Person.PersonID \\<<int`

Now a long time ago I did see a nice pattern like this:

```
interface BusinessObject<TKey,TEntity> //TKey as in ID
{
 TKey ID;
 TEntity SearchById(TKey id);
}
```

So you could do this:

```
class Person : BusinessObject<Person, int> {}
```

OR

```
class FileRecord : BusinessObject<FileRecord, Guid> {}
```

Wonder if it helped but it just came to mind.

Comment: *@giddy*, the OP wants IDs to have their own types so that they cannot get mixed up, i.e. such that an assignment of the form `BananaFactory.ID = JohnSmith.ID` will issue a compiler warning. It actually seems like a good idea, even if it probably won't prevent many bugs. (How often does one actually mix up different types of IDs? Most likely, this is a rare error.)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. Unfortunately I'm dealing with a large legacy system that doesn't have cleanly or uniformly applied entity objects, everything is very mixed up and I'm looking for a way to disentangle it a little.  I'd certainly like to get there some day.

Comment: @stakx ok Your example really clears it up.  @chillitom Maybe you can have something like `IIdentifier<T>` dunno. ;)

Comment: @giddy, sorry to intrude again; Such an interface would lead to more homogeneous types, but, in the case of `struct` types, to more boxing/unboxing. You could then just as well define ID types as `class`.

Comment: @stakx -- Rare but hard to spot in many cases. The system I'm looking at at the moment deals with several databases in places in the code you can deal with an entities or methods with 2 or 3 IDs all for the same thing but completely incompatible trying to pick the correct value from something like person.Id, person.OurPersonId, person.Sys1PersonId and person.ExternalId can easily induce many errors.

Comment: @stakx yes I meant an interface `IIdentifier<T>` implemented in a class. Similar to @mgronber 's answer. @chillitom ah I can see how that could be a problem.