# DDD repository input parameters

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Which is suggested way to implement  `_customRoleRepository` in the following examples?
Following code is executed in the application service.

```
var user = _userRepository.GetById(1);
var customRole = _customRoleRepository.GetById(user.CustomRoleId);
```

or

```
var user = _userRepository.GetById(1);
var customRole = _customRoleRepository.GetForUser(user);
```

Comment: what are the user and their role being loaded for?

Comment: @tomliversidge To create auth token and grab role permissions to tie it for that token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the two options I would probably go for the first one, which keeps consistency of accessing by an ID.

If possible, it might be preferable to load the custom role when you load the user to avoid another round trip to the database, especially if this is a common operation. This could be implemented as a read model.

This is presuming you have modelled your aggregates correctly... :)

Comment: Something like CQRS?

Comment: Terminology can depend on who you talk to :) But I often use the term CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation) for when there is a separate datastore for reading that is pre-projected onto exactly the read models required by the responses.  It is asynchonously kept up to date based on an event stream.  However, another equally valid technique is CQS (Command Query Separation) which is when you have a set of Queries that run standard queries against the write model persistence store.  The queries are _separated_ in the application, but the read model is not fully _segregated_.

Comment: So for me, implementing a read model query that simply joined Users table to CustomRoles table and returned a read model dto would be CQS.  But also, I think it's only a good idea if the data is going straight up to the UI or API response data.  If you are going to use the data returned in order to interact with the domain aggregates/entities, what you're doing with repositories is better because you're using domain models with domain models and keeping their access strategies independent.

Comment: Thanks for explaining difference between CQS and CQRS. I always had an impression it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say it but in a DDD environment, my answer would be neither.

In your first example, the role repository can be ignorant of the user domain which is good but it means the application needs to know that to get the role it needs to pull an id out of the user and then query another repository.  In other words, the application is acting as a mapper between user and role.

In the second example, the roles repository now needs to know about the user domain.  Not great but on the other hand the application no longer needs to know about roleId.  So that is good.  Classic sort of trade off between the two approaches.

But in both cases the application still needs two repositories to get it's information.  What happens when more relations are needed?  The number of repositories can quickly grow and things become a mess.

In Domain Driven Design you should try to think in terms of aggregate roots(AR) and domain contexts.  For your example context, the user is an AR and the role becomes a child.  So you might have:

```
var user = _userFinder.GetById(1);
var customRole = user.CustomRole;
```

That hides most of the implementation details from you application and allows you to focus on what your domain entities actually need to do.

Comment: CustomRole represents another AggregateRoot within BC. It has it's entities (permissions), etc. Multuple users can share same CustomRole. What you suggest, is to treat CustomRole as a value object, and when CustomRole gets updated, I would have to propagate that change to all users within that role?

Comment: Two ars within the same bc sounds like trouble.  In your example, I would consider the role to be a value object.  I would have a different bc for updating the role and yes send a notification to tell users the role has changed.  Of course much of this depends on if you actually have complex business logic to deal with.  Hard to make specific recommendations without knowing the big picture.

Comment: By the way, I think these sorts of questions get a better response on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wouldn't go that far and say that AgrRoots within the same BC sounds like a trouble. Vaughn Vernon in his Implementing DD Design book gave an example of Identity and Access Context, and it had 4 aggregate roots within the context. I do not have Users or Roles contexts. I have identity & permissions bounded context. IMO AR serves as consistency boundary, while context describes model of my problem.

Comment: @Cerad "Two ars within the same bc sounds like trouble" That is absolutely incorrect. ARs are not sub-domains. Ideally there should be one BC per sub-domain and it is very likely that there will be several ARs per BC. If your BCs all have aggregate names then you are doing it incorrectly. BCs are autonomous components, but there is a cost associated to this dissociation (e.g. having an anti-corruption layer, eventual consistency, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Both are equally valid, depending on your needs.  `GetForUser` would be good if you want to ensure the calling code has a valid User aggregate before you try and retrieve the roles - while it does couple the customRoleRepository to knowledge of the User aggregate, if you want to require the calling code to have a valid User aggregate, then that coupling has a purpose.

`GetByUserId` is more consistent with `GetById` and has less coupling, so if in your context it doesn't matter to call `GetByUserId` even if the client doesn't have a valid User aggregate, then that's fine too.

If you are loading ById, I've also found using typed identity valueobjects can be quite helpful in providing an extra level of type safety - some conversation about the pros and cons here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5377460/6720449 and here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dddcqrs/WQ9zRtW3Gbg